# Understanding EatChar function

Tags: vimrc

In using an `iabbrev`, vim help gives the following example of how it can be used to ignore the character after typing in the keyword:

Towards the bottom of [`Abbreviations`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#Abbreviations):

```
You can even do more complicated things.  For example, to consume the space
typed after an abbreviation:
   func Eatchar(pat)
      let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
      return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
   endfunc
   iabbr <silent> if if ()<Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
```

How exactly does this work? For example, I'm clear on up to the `<C-R>=` to enter the expression register to invoke the output of the `EatChar` command and it is passing any space-likechar with `'\s'`, but what do these two lines do?

```
let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
```

Additionally:

- `nr2char` returns the character of an asci number,
  for example: `echom nr2char(80)` ==> `P`
- How does `getchar(0)` work? Every time I try that I get `0`, so what is that doing?
- Finally, it 'returns' either a character or empty string. But where does that go exactly? How does that 'eat' a character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but what do these two lines do?
>
> ```
> let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
> return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
> ```

The first line consumes a character from the typeahead buffer; if the latter is empty, `getchar()` doesn't wait for a character to be written inside, thanks to the optional `0` argument.

The second line spits back the consumed character, but only if it's *not* a whitespace.

---

[More details](https://github.com/lacygoill/wiki/blob/master/vim/abbrev.md#how-to-redefine-my-abbreviation-so-that-its-done-automatically):

```
fu s:eat_space()
   let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
   return c =~# '\s' ? '' : c
endfu
inorea <silent> if if ()<left><c-r>=<sid>eat_space()<cr>
```

Here's what happens:

- you type `i`; it's written in the typeahead buffer, then executed (i.e. inserted in your buffer)
- you type `f`; same thing
- you type space which should be a non-keyword character:

  - it's written in the typeahead buffer
  - Vim checks whether the text before the cursor matches an abbreviation
  - it finds one; as a result, it removes its lhs from your buffer, and
    inserts its rhs into the typeahead; i.e. `if` is removed from your buffer,
    and `if ()<left><c-r>=<sid>eat_space()<cr>` is inserted in the typeahead
    in front of the space
  - the typeahead is executed; when `<c-r>=<sid>eat_space()<cr>` is executed,
    `s:eat_space()` consumes the last remaining space from the typeahead (via `getchar()`)
  - the typeahead buffer is now empty, and the space is not executed
    (i.e. inserted in your buffer)

You may wonder why `if ()...` is written in the typeahead buffer.  I think it has to, because if you define a recursive abbreviation (`iab` vs `inorea`), mappings are applied; that can only happen in the typeahead buffer.

---

You could probably replace this line:

```
return c =~# '\s' ? '' : c
```

With:

```
return ''
```

However, if you were to use `s:eat_space()` in another abbreviation, and for some reason you wanted to use it in a different position in the rhs, the function could wrongly consume some non-whitespace character which would be unexpected. So the current statement, while not necessary here, is a good practice.

---

The fact that `getchar()` consumes the typeahead buffer is not really documented, but it's briefly mentioned at `:h :map-<expr> /typeahead`:

> ```
> You can use getchar(), it consumes typeahead if there is any.
> ```

---

> How does getchar(0) work? Every time I try that I get 0, so what is that doing?

From `:h getchar()`:

> If [expr] is 0, only get a character when one is available.
> Return zero otherwise.

No character is available in the typeahead buffer when you run `:echo getchar(0)`, so 0 is returned.

Comment: wow, this is such a great answer, thanks for taking the time. And the link at https://github.com/lacygoill/wiki/blob/master/vim/ is great. Did you create all that?